# How can I get keys in mapA as keys in mapB is a substring of key in mapA?

Tags: java, search, hashmap, substring

I have two maps here:

**mapA**

```
Map<String, String> mapA = new HashMap<>();
mapA.put("aaa|111|osdf", "value1");
mapA.put("bbb|222|dfsf", "value2");
...
```

**mapB**

```
Map<String, String> mapB = new HashMap<>();
mapB.put("aaa", "valueM");
mapB.put("bbb", "valueN");
...
```

Now I want to get keys in mapA if key in mapB is substring of keys in mapA, just like:

```
mapB.forEach((key, value) -> {
  if (mapA.containsKey(key)) {
     // This is not what I want, because key in mapB is substring of key in mapA.
     // nested loop is not suggested here.

 ​ }

})
```

**OUTPUTS**

```
aaa|111|osdf
bbb|222|dfsf
```

How can I get keys in mapA as keys in mapB is a substring of key in mapA?

Comment: As per your example seems like first part of key in mapA like 'aaa' or 'bbb' (part before first '|') can be there in mapB as a key. is that assumption is correct?

Comment: Correct, but in some reason, mapB should be traversed

Comment: for mapA can we use Map<Custom, String> in place of Map<String, String>? if yes then in  Custom class we can modify equals and hashCode to use 'String' before first pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
 mapB.forEach((k, v) -> {
            String key = mapA.entrySet().stream()
                    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().contains(k))
                    .findFirst()
                    .get()
                    .getKey();
            System.out.println(key);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**containsKey(Object key)** will check that this map contains a mapping for a key k such that **(key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k))**. However in your case **aaa|111|osdf** or **bbb|222|dfsf** considered as single key.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class MapMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, String> mapA = new HashMap<>();
        mapA.put("aaa|111|osdf", "value1");
        mapA.put("bbb|222|dfsf", "value2");

        Map<String, String> mapB = new HashMap<>();
        mapB.put("aaa", "valueM");
        mapB.put("bbb", "valueN");

        mapB.forEach((k, v) -> {
            Set<String> mapAKeySet = mapA.keySet();
            mapAKeySet.stream().filter(key -> key.contains(k)).forEach(System.out::println);
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know containsKey shouldnot work. I just ask for solution to get that single key in mapA.

Comment: @zhwlx22 I updated my code check that.

Comment: I think this is a nested loop solution?

Answer (score 0):

You may change your comparison block to the following:

```
mapB.forEach( ( key, value ) -> {
    mapA.keySet().forEach( k -> { if( k.contains( key ) ) System.out.println( k ); } );
} );
```

You may change the `if` condition to `startsWith()` or some other check that `String` provides and suits your needs better.

This **may** print a key multiple times depending upon the actual keys in both maps. So, you may instead of printing, collect the matched keys in a `Set` inside the `if` block and print later.

---

### Using a custom map implementation

This only ensures that the looping is shifted into the `Map` implementation. However, the looping is not avoided. I would love to see a technique that doesn't use looping over the keys.

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
    class CustomHashMap extends HashMap<String, String>{
        /* This method will find the matching keys. May be changed to return List<String>. */
        public String getStartingKey( String key ) {
            if( key == null || !( key instanceof String ) ) return null;
            for( String k : keySet() ) if( k.startsWith( key.toString() ) ) return k;
            return null;
        }
    };
    
    CustomHashMap mapA = new CustomHashMap();
    
    mapA.put( "aaa|111|osdf", "value1" );
    mapA.put( "bbb|222|dfsf", "value2" );
    mapA.put( "ccc|222|dfsf", "value2" );

    Map<String, String> mapB = new HashMap<>();
    mapB.put( "aaa", "valueM" );
    mapB.put( "bbb", "valueN" );

    mapB.forEach( ( key, value ) -> {
        System.out.println( mapA.getStartingKey( key ) );
    } );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is a nested loop solution, which is not what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Looping can only be delegated to some other place, that is all, I think. Are you OK with using a different `Map` implementation other than `HashMap`?

Comment: Any suggestions with a different `Map`?

Comment: Posting an edit with a custom Map

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> mapA = new HashMap<>();
    mapA.put("aaa|111|osdf", "value1");
    mapA.put("bbb|222|dfsf", "value2");

    Map<String, String> mapB = new HashMap<>();
    mapB.put("aaa", "valueM");
    mapB.put("bbb", "valueN");
    
    for (String aKey : mapA.keySet())
        for (String bKey : mapB.keySet())
            if (aKey.contains(bKey)) {
                System.out.println(aKey);
                break;
            }
}
```

output:

```
aaa|111|osdf
bbb|222|dfsf
```

Or

```
    mapA.keySet().stream()
        .filter(aKey -> mapB.keySet().stream()
            .anyMatch(bKey -> aKey.contains(bKey)))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```